# required set timeout need in if else condition in following changes

Tags: javascript, angular

```js
  ngonit()
{
this.timeout();
}
   //timer
 timer:any;
  time() {
  this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(this.timer);
       this.openDialog();
  }, 10000)
  console.log(this.timer);
  }
  timeout() {
  
   document.addEventListener('keypress', () => {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.time();
    });
    document.addEventListener('click', () => {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.time();
    });
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
      clearTimeout(this.timer);
      this.time();
    })
 }
```

If the User is not access the page for 6 seconds we need to alert the user your logged out. so I want to show the popup(warn) message when user is idle for 5 seconds in if condition  and  the else if i need to show another popup 1 seconds your logged out if the user is not access the page.so totally after 6 seconds we need to show the 2nd popup message to user is loggedout. the below code i have returned for just showing popup when user is idle 5 seconds.can you edit this?

Comment: `var timer:any;` isn't valid JavaScript

Comment: `cosnole.log` isn't valid JavaScript. Might want to proofread or try running your code before posting it.

Comment: tommyO i have updated,please check..

Comment: ngu I have updated please check.

Comment: I hope the user does not need to blow their nose while on this page. lol

Comment: So inside of setTimeout, start another timer.... that will do the logout

Comment: Even if you display the `alert` provided by the browser you cannot programmatically close it. You will have to use a modal dialog provided by a 3rd party library or design one of you own

Comment: epascarello,Sushanth ,I have updated my changes in the code  please check

Answer (score 1):

to start `var timer:any;` is invalid in javascript;

Your timer needs to be setted to `5000` which is 5 seconds, then inside it always clear the timer (to avoid multiple clicks calling the same function) and when the timer reaches 5 seconds, start another timer with 1000ms, this one will call the `out()` function.

Inside `out()` you don't need to add a listener to the document every time, just use a boolen to check if it was already added or not. adding the listener a single time is sufficient.

Also, since `session()` is a function, to it start at the beggining, you must call that function at least once.

```js
var timer;
var listenersAdded = false;
function session() {
  clearTimeout(this.timer)
  this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("please access the page ur going to logout in 1 seconds");
      this.timer = setTimeout(() => out(), 1000)
  }, 5000)  
}

function out() {
 console.log("logged out");
 if (listenersAdded != true){
  listenersAdded = true
  document.addEventListener('keypress', session);
  document.addEventListener('click', session); 
 }
}

session()
```

But you know that is almost impossible to read the message about logout and do something in less than a second, right?

Comment: Calvin Nunes ,I have updated my changes in the code  please check i amusing angular

Comment: well, since you started with one question then you modify it completely when the people start to answer and help, I'm not going to modify my answer. Also, I would not have answered if you have told that is angular, because I don't know angular

Comment: Calvin Nunes this is fine now but when i load asap it is getting the logged out message

Comment: Calvin Nunes,thank you very much...but people aasked above thats why i updated my question for pop up

Comment: Calvin Nunes, suppose user clicks ok i want to cancel this timer this.timer = setTimeout(() => out(), 1000) ..

Comment: When people ask things is because you didn't let the question clear, so you edit it but mantain the initial idea, if necessary you add a new paragraph with an `EDIT:` note putting in it the new information.

Comment: About your new question of when user clicks "ok", i don't know where is the ok button and you probably need a create a listener to click when the timeout starts to clear it when the click occurs

Comment: Calvin Nunes:I am sorry but most people understand javascript thats y i dint mention third party library modelpopup.

Comment: can you update the above code  when user clicks ok it should remine in the page?